# Connecting to MySQL using SSH in Rstudio on OSX

Tags: mysql, r, macos, ssh

I know this was discussed here but I am at a lose.
I have an R code connecting to MySQL that was working fine. Recently, we changed the connection to be via SSH and now, I cannot connect.
When I try to connect to the same MySQL server, using SSH i get the following:

```
    Warning: Error in .local: Failed to connect to database: Error: 
    Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server.url.' (57)

    Stack trace (innermost first):
        47: .local
        46: dbConnect
        45: dbConnect
    Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
    Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on...
```

this is my piece of code that runs fine and establishes a connection:

```
system(paste("chmod 600 ", MySSHkey))
system(paste("ssh -v -f -N -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ", MySSHkey, " -L 1234:127.0.0.1:1234 ", MySSHuser,"@",MySSHhost, sep = ""))
```

then, when running the dbConnect part:

```
oConn <- dbConnect(
 drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
 dbname = MySQLDBname,
 host = MySQLHost,
 username = MySQLName,
 password = MySQLPswrd
)
```

I get the error at the top....
What am I missing?

Thank you for the help!

Btw, I also tried connecting to host 127.0.0.1:1234 instead of MySQLHost and it did not work. It gave me the following reply:

```
Failed to connect to database: Error: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake: reading inital communication packet', system error: 57
```

Comment: Try to connect to host `127.0.0.1:1234` instead of `MySQLHost`, `ssh` creates a forwarding link between that address and the server.

Comment: I don't know, it might even be a separate issue. Please edit this new finding into your question.